# Run Google AppEngine Application on IntelliJ 13

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have the [guestbook appengine application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction?hl=es) working in the command line. For  faster development I need to work in the IntelliJ IDEA IDE. But, I can't run the application. I guess the problem is configuration. How should I configure the IDE?

When I open the pom project and try to run it, IntelliJ shows `Warning: App Engine facet not found in 'guestbook-war:war exploded' artifact`. After I configure all the other options I can run the application. But, IDEA then shows:

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate Z:\demos\google-app-engine\guestbook\classes\artifacts\guestbook\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Z:\demos\google-app-engine\guestbook\classes\artifacts\guestbook\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
    ... 27 more

com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.reportDeferredConfigurationException(DevAppServerImpl.java:466)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid appengine-web.xml(Z:\demos\google-app-engine\guestbook\classes\artifacts\guestbook\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml) - Could not locate D:\demos\google-app-engine\guestbook\classes\artifacts\guestbook\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:265)
    ... 8 more
```

IDEA tries to run the application from the `classes` directory, not from the `target` directory. Where can I configure this? I saw the `classes` directory and there isn't anything important in it. It only has folders and jars referred to by appengine, but nothing about the project.
How can I configure this?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue. Thanks

Comment: idea allows to set working directory which can be explicitly set in its un configurations dialog

Comment: I am using Intellij 14 to build app engine applications and it works great. When you create the project you specify that it is a GAE project. And in the File/Project Structure you need to let Intellij know where you installed the google sdk. This is an old question but if you haven't already upgrading to the new version should make your life much easier.